# VHDL Syntax Errors for Counter

Tags: vhdl, quartus-ii

Here is my code for an n mod k counter in VHDL. I keep getting various syntax errors but can't seem to pin down exactly what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

```
   library ieee;
   use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
   use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
  use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

 entity nmodkcounter is generic (
n : natural := 4;
k : natural := 10);

port ( clock : in STD_LOGIC;
reset_n : in STD_LOGIC;
load    : in STD_LOGIC;
settime : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR;
Q1 :  out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0);
Q2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));


signal value : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
begin
PROCESS(clock, reset_n, load, k)
begin
if ((reset_n = ’0’) and (load = '0')) then --Resets LINE 22
value <= (OTHERS => ’0’); -- LINE 23
elsif (clock’event and clock = ’1’) --Counts up at rising edge LINE 24
then value <= (value + 1);
elsif (reset_n = '0' and load = '1') then --Sets time to loaded value
value <= settime;
end if;

if(value = k - 1)  -- Resets count when value reaches k
then
Q1 <= '1'; -- Loads Q1 with 1 to send to next counter
value <= '0';
else
Q1 <= '0';
end if;
end process;

Q2 <= value; -- To output to display
 end nmodkcounter;
```

[image: Errors]

Comment: From my experience, VHDL is annoying as hell when it comes to errors. Regardless, those n and k declarations may be the source of your errors. Can't tell though; you should post the errors you are getting in the question which would be more helpful

Comment: Hi sorry I will in a sec

Comment: they are all syntax near text '...' expected '...' if that helps for now but will post screenshot in moment

Comment: You need to post the errors and post your source with line numbers otherwise you can't correlate the two.

Comment: Also, you're doing all sorts of stuff outside the clocked part in a clocked process. That's just asking for trouble. Assigning single bits to 4-bit vectors won't help either.

Comment: For the record, I'm afraid this is pretty bad VHDL. You need to broadly design a synchronous digital circuit then write the VHDL to implement it. Logic circuit first, VHDL second.

Comment: Well the prof asked for asynchronous reset so that has to be outside of the clocked process. And how do I assign the right number of bits to vector when the the size of the vector is variable?

Comment: Have a search on the interweb for a VHDL clocked process with asynchronous reset, you'll find the same template: process(rst, clk) begin if (rst = '1') then x elsif rising_edge(clk) then y end if; end process;  Everything in your clocked process is in y. x is just reset assignments. Use ModelSim to see it in action under a testbench, not a synthesis tool.

Comment: asynchronous reset is **not** outside of the _process_, it is outside of the `if rising_edge(clk)`-statement. And where is your test bench? You should always test your code using a test bench before you synthesize it.

Answer (score 1):

You have the errors because you have wrong structure of the code. You need to close `entity` declaration and start `architecture` description:

```
...
Q2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(n-1 downto 0));
end nmodkcounter;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF nmodkcounter IS 

    signal value : std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
...
```

Next error is using parameter from generic in sensitivity list `PROCESS(clock, reset_n, load, k)`. You need to remove from sensitivity list the `k` parameter.

Next error in follow assignments:

```
if(value = k - 1)  -- Resets count when value reaches k
then
    Q1 <= '1'; -- Loads Q1 with 1 to send to next counter
    value <= '0';
else
    Q1 <= '0';
end if;
```

Here the signals `Q1` and `value` are `std_logic_vector` but you try to assign just one bit.

And as you forgot to start `architecture` description you need to close it in the end as `end behavior;` So your code should have the following structure:

```
entity nmodkcounter is 
    generic (
    ...
    );
    port (
    ...
    );
end nmodkcounter;

ARCHITECTURE behavior OF nmodkcounter IS 
...
begin
...
end behavior;
```